# How to improve the effectiveness of a camcorder's built-in microphone

Tags: audio-recording

We video-tape work meetings  but some speakers are quiet and we cannot pick up comments from them.

- We don't have the manpower to tape from the front and back and then splice the two.
- Also, my camcorder does not have audio-input functionality to plug in a microphone that could be set in the middle of the room.

Any suggestions would be welcome..we are not experts here, unfortunately.

Comment: If your camcorder does not support audio-input, what sort of solution do you hope will be suggested? I'd imagine any solution would involve an external audio pickup device.

Comment: Telling us the camera's make and model would help us better answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be to mix the input from multiple microphones.  If you get a simple mixer, you can have them all combined and not have to match it up after the fact.  You would just leave all microphones turned up and which ever one has someone talking would play through.

You could also potentially use a really sensitive mic with a device called a compressor.  This would prevent the louder people from being too loud while still having enough sensitivity to get the quieter people.  It will be a cheaper than a mixer and multiple mics, but it is also going to be much noisier.

You really don't have any option other than to get a new camera that can support one of the two options or to try and record audio separately to something like a Zoom H4N and then combine it on a computer after the fact.  There is no magic trick that is going to allow you to use such a limited camera in the context you describe.

Comment: In the question is said that they only have one camcorder with no possibility to even add an external mic. Which multiple mics/mixers/compressors are you talking about?

Comment: @EugeneS - ah, missed that.  I will update accordingly.